# How can you ensure the state of a button in a nav bar is set to active onclick when the route is for that button?

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar

In my react app, I want to be able to have an svg button (in my navbar) change color when the button's route is active, or switch color depending on which button's route is active that was pressed/selected.

Example: You click on the settings button in the nav bar, the route changes to the settings back (already have this working), and the button which is an svg changes color from blue (unselected) to blue selected (what I don't have working). Then if I click on the Profile button, this button svg turns blue, and the settings button goes back to the non-active color.

I am using styled-components, and have the onHover effect working for the button. I think this is focus, but i haven't been able to get it to stay the color. It might be a hook thing too, but I'm not sure.

Curious what others think?

Comment: Please include some code, this is difficult to understand.

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you are trying to do, with specific details about any issues. As-is your question is a bit too broad and reads as asking for recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useLocation` hook from `react-router-dom`. And use it like this

`let location = useLocation();`

Then you can use the `pathname` attribute to specify the path, and when the pathname is equal to the selected tab path name , you can add the style to the tab as per your requirement.

Like here

```
<NavLink style={location.pathname === "/" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/">Home</NavLink>
```

I have added custom `tabStyle` (which is chequered background) here defined as below:

```
  let tabStyle = {
    backgroundImage:
    "repeating-conic-gradient(#808080 0% 25%, black 0% 50%) ",
    textShadow:'2px 0px black',
    border:'1px white solid'
 }
```

You can use it in any `Navbar Component` like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const NavbarComponent = () => {

  let location = useLocation();

  let tabStyle = {
    backgroundImage:
    "repeating-conic-gradient(#808080 0% 25%, black 0% 50%) ",
    textShadow:'2px 0px black',
    border:'1px white solid'
 }

  return (
    <>
      <nav variant="pills" className="navbar" style={{ borderBottom: "1px solid white" }}>
        <ul className="nav nav-pills">
          <li>
            <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/">Home</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/about" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/about">About</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink style={location.pathname === "/FAQ" ? tabStyle:{}} to="/FAQ">FAQ</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
};

export default NavbarComponent;
```